# How to fix IDE0017 when using File Dialogs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, openfiledialog, object-initialization

I am getting three "Suggestions" IDE0017 Object Initialization cab be simplified.

```
    private string dbSelect()
    {
        // This is the User File Name Selection
        OpenFileDialog openThis = new OpenFileDialog();
        openThis.DefaultExt = "sqlite";
        openThis.Filter = "SQLite Databases|*.sqlite";
        if (openThis.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return openThis.FileName;
        }
        return null;
    }


    public bool openDatabase()
    {
        OpenFileDialog openThis = new OpenFileDialog();
        openThis.DefaultExt = "sqlite";
        openThis.Filter = "SQLite Databases|*.sqlite";
        if (openThis.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + openThis.FileName + ";Version=3;");
            m_dbConnection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


   public bool createDatabase()
    {
        SaveFileDialog createThis = new SaveFileDialog();
        createThis.DefaultExt = "sqlite";
        createThis.Filter = "SQLite Databases|*.sqlite";

        if (createThis.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK || createThis.FileName.Trim() == "")
        {
            return false;
        }

        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + createThis.FileName + ";Version=3;");
        m_dbConnection.Open();

        return true;
  }
```

How do I reform these to simplify them? They've been fine until VS2017...

And, so far, Google hasn't really helped.

And, I am not sure I like the idea that simplification means placing everything in a single line.

I was taught that readability is important and all in one line is just plain cluttered.

But, I'd hate to miss a trick... I suppose I can just turn it off...

Comment: If you mouse-over the line you should get a wee lightbulb icon, click its dropdown & you can preview the change & have VS make it for you.

Comment: This is NOT an error, just a suggetion made by Visual Studio to make your code easier to understand.

Comment: Where do you get these suggestions, on which lines?

Comment: OpenFileDialog openThis = new OpenFileDialog()
{
//data initializer
}

Comment: Alex K - Thanks learned something! 
Poul Bak - I knew that, it's in the first line. :)
Tim Schmeiter - on the actual dialog definition lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uppon creating a new instance of anything instead of doing `MyType myVariable = new MyType();` and then set every property from `myVariable` line by line you can do `MyType myVariable = new MyType() {};` and between the `{}` you can set the properties you want to set.

For the `SaveFileDialog` for example you can do :

```
SaveFileDialog createThis = new SaveFileDialog() 
{
    DefaultExt = "sqlite", 
    Filter = "SQLite Databases|*.sqlite"
};
```